# Derivation of the cumulative distribution function for the beta-binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, hypergeometric-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, beta-function

Let $X$ be a random variable following a beta-binomial distribution:

$$
X \sim \mathrm{BetBin}(n, \alpha, \beta) \; .
$$

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution), the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is

$$
F_X(x) = {n \choose x} \frac{\mathrm{B}(x+\alpha,n-x+\beta)}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)} {}_3 F_2(a; b; x)
$$

where ${}_3 F_2(a, b; x)$ is supposed to be the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)

$$
{}_3 F_2([1, -x, n-x+\beta]; [n-x+1, 1-x-\alpha]; 1) \; .
$$

Trying to derive the CDF by hand, i.e. as

$$
F_X(x) = \mathrm{Pr}(X \leq x) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{x} f_X(i) = \sum_{i=0}^{x} {n \choose i} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{B}(\alpha+i,\beta+n-i)}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)} \; ,
$$

I have managed to get up to this point:

$$
F_X(x) = \frac{1}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta+n)} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{x} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+i) \cdot \Gamma(\beta+n-i)}{\Gamma(i+1) \cdot \Gamma(n-i+1)} \; .
$$

Can somebody tell me how to arrive at the equation that is given on Wikipedia?